# div and class not showing up

Tags: php, html, css, barcode

I'm testing a barcode on my website but for some reason the div with the class="b128" which stands for the barcodes is not showing up. If I test the same source code on another website it does show up but with different styling.

Does anyone know how I can make this source code show up and keep the original styling at the same time?

```
<style>
div.b128{
border-left: 1px black solid;
height: 60px;
}   
</style>

<?php
global $char128asc,$char128charWidth;
$char128asc=' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~';                 
$char128wid = array(
'212222','222122','222221','121223','121322','131222','122213','122312','132212','221213', // 0-9 
'221312','231212','112232','122132','122231','113222','123122','123221','223211','221132', // 10-19 
'221231','213212','223112','312131','311222','321122','321221','312212','322112','322211', // 20-29             
'212123','212321','232121','111323','131123','131321','112313','132113','132311','211313', // 30-39 
'231113','231311','112133','112331','132131','113123','113321','133121','313121','211331', // 40-49 
'231131','213113','213311','213131','311123','311321','331121','312113','312311','332111', // 50-59 
'314111','221411','431111','111224','111422','121124','121421','141122','141221','112214', // 60-69 
'112412','122114','122411','142112','142211','241211','221114','413111','241112','134111', // 70-79 
'111242','121142','121241','114212','124112','124211','411212','421112','421211','212141', // 80-89 
'214121','412121','111143','111341','131141','114113','114311','411113','411311','113141', // 90-99
'114131','311141','411131','211412','211214','211232','23311120'   );                      // 100-106

////Define Function
function bar128($text) {                        // Part 1, make list of widths
  global $char128asc,$char128wid;               
  $w = $char128wid[$sum = 104];                         // START symbol
  $onChar=1;
  for($x=0;$x<strlen($text);$x++)                               // GO THRU TEXT GET LETTERS
if (!( ($pos = strpos($char128asc,$text[$x])) === false )){ // SKIP NOT FOUND CHARS
  $w.= $char128wid[$pos];
  $sum += $onChar++ * $pos;
}                   
  $w.= $char128wid[ $sum % 103 ].$char128wid[106];          //Check Code, then END
                                            //Part 2, Write rows
  $html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>";              
  for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2)                         // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
$html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div>";    
  return "$html<tr><td  colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2><b>$text</table>";        
}
?>
<?php
$test = "12345";
echo '<div style="border:3px double #ababab; padding:5px;margin:5px auto;width:135px;">';
echo bar128(stripslashes($test));
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Why do you not use svg for this purpose?

Comment: @PavelGatnar I'm actually not familiar with svg, but I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing most of your tags. Try this:

```
    $html = "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>";
    for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($w); $x += 2)                         // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
        $html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div></td>";
    return "$html</tr><tr><td  colspan=" . strlen($w) . " align=center><font family=arial size=2><b>$text</b></font></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't show up. I tried it on another website where it does show up but the styling changes again from the original one.